# SharePoint General Rule

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-actions, infopath-rules

I have a field in SharePoint that I want to force if another field contains information (any date at all). Below I will explain:

Below I have two fields (Actual CTR/On Time), I want to set a rule that forces someone if Actual CTR has a date the On Time field must be filled in. I am very aware of the rules in InfoPath and how they are used but for some reason I am totally lost on this rule...

[image: CTR]

Answer (score 0):

You would create a validation rule on the On Time field, something along the lines of `If Actual CRT is not blank and On Time is blank` and provide your screen tip message.

Comment: thank you for this but it's not working with a drop down menu with the on time section? When I go to submit this form an error pops up.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: The error states a validation error.

_InfoPath cannot submit the form, because it contains validation errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values)._

Comment: oh derp, you'd need to add an additional condition where On Time is blank.

Comment: Wouldn't this counter-dict what I am trying to do?

Comment: You want it so that if a CTR date is specified, they have to supply On Time right? So this would throw a error if there is a value in CTR and nothing is selected in on time.

Comment: You are correct my friend. I did not think it through and I have just tested this method and works out.